# Django admin shows Post object in lieu of title

Tags: python, django

Really new to Django so bear with me :) 
I am running into an issue to display the posts titles in the Django admin.

I have tried both in Python 3

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    tags = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=400)

def __str__(self):
   return self.title
```

and Python 2

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    tags = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=400)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

but unfortunately in the Django admin I see 
"Post object "in the list of posts

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: is the indentation correct in your code ? meaning `__str__` should be inside the class block

Comment: Are you sure your methods `__str__` and `__unicode__` are inside your model? (indentation)

Comment: I think that the indentation is correct, I get no error and it seems to be fine. I even removed the space just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    tags = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: wow this is great and works fine on python 3!  how can I make it work on python 2 too ? :)

Comment: I am using this in Python 2.7 so it will work in Python 2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

For those who might come here after me, you'd have to add this method inside the model class.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Make sure it's indented right or else it might not work.

Answer (score 0):

Add your post models to the administration site. Edit the admin.py file of your app and make it look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Post
admin.site.register(Post)
```

The admin has many hooks for customization check [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/)

Comment: He said: "but unfortunately in the Django admin I see "Post object "in the list of posts". This means he already registered them.

Comment: I already have this in the admin.py from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post
admin.site.register(Post)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have Django return, say, a MyPerson object whenever you query for Person objects. A queryset for Person objects will return those types of objects. The whole point of proxy objects is that code relying on the original Person will use those and your own code can use the extensions you included (that no other code is relying on anyway

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[Know more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#querysets-still-return-the-model-that-was-requested)

Answer (score 0):

For those who come after, make sure post is in lowercase.
And after which make migrations again.

make sure name='post' not 'Post'...

**migrations.AlterModelOptions(
name='post',**